# Are stop-returning functions still stopped when inside nested functions?

Tags: meteor, meteor-tracker

> In addition, the following functions which return an object with a
>   stop method, if called from a reactive computation, are stopped when
>   the computation is rerun or stopped:
>
> Tracker.autorun (nested) Meteor.subscribe observe() and
>   observeChanges() on cursors

This means that the observe stops here:

```
Tracker.autorun ->
  cursor.observe()
```

But what about here?

```
Tracker.autorun ->
  Tracker.nonReactive ->
    cursor.observe()
```

Comment: It is not just a nested function, it is a `nonreactive` context, so an observation within it will not be stopped automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a `MiniMongo` reactive handle (`find()`, `observe()`, etc.) is created in a reactive computation, `MiniMongo` will detect it and attach a listener to the computation's `onInvalidate` that will stop the handle when the computation is invalidated (or stopped).

It does not matter whether this is done directly in the `autorun` callback 
or in a function that is called from the callback it, as long as it is done synchronously (i.e, while in the context of the same computation).

There is one notable exception: a non-reactive callback.

A `Tracker.nonreactive` callback is fired within a non-reactive context, so the [current computation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/tracker/tracker.js#L585) is set to `null` and `Tracker.active` is set to `false`. Under those conditions, `MiniMongo` [will not attach the aforementioned listener](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/203c0aba85834ba00874bb49afe9435a5bc761bf/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js#L407) and the change observer will not be stopped automatically.

You can stop it manually, though:

```js
const MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);
const cursor1 = MyCollection.find({foo: 'bar'});
const cursor2 = MyCollection.find({foo: 'baz'});

let observeCallback = {
  added(doc) {
    console.log('added', doc);
  }
};


let handle = Tracker.autorun(function(c) { // c is the computation object
  cursor1.observe(observeCallback); // will be automatically stopped

  Tracker.nonreactive(function() {
    let observer = cursor2.observe(observeCallback);
    c.onStop(function() {
      observer.stop(); // explicitly stops the observer
    })

  });

});

MyCollection.insert({foo: 'bar'});
MyCollection.insert({foo: 'baz'});

handle.stop();
```